# How to put headers into devel/include folder with catkin_make?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, devel, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a lib in my package and want to share its header.

According to "how-to" I use this command:

```
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION})
```

But after "catkin_make" command no headers are in devel/include folder. (Lib itself successfully appears in /devel/lib folder)

When I run "catkin_make install" command headers appear in install/include folder properly.

What am i doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150306/how-to-put-headers-into-devel/include-folder-with-catkin_make?/) by [Mike Charikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/14571/mike-charikov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2014-04-08

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is fine as it is. The headers don't need to be copied from you package source folder to the `devel/include` folder. Just make sure that you export the include folder in your CMake file using:

```
catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS include)
```

And if you use your own headers add the folder to the include directories using:

```
include_directories(include)
```

Then any downstream package will find you package headers when adding the include directories with:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS your_package)
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Charikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/14571/mike-charikov/) on 2014-04-08**:
Thanks. That's was my folly: missed that find_package thing.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-04-29**:
This works fine for building, but some IDEs won't be able to find the include directory, as this method doesn't add it to the CPATH variable. The devel/include directory *does* get added to the CPATH variable, though, so generated messages can be found by the IDE, but not the package's own headers.

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2014-11-07**:
Is there a way of getting your headers into the devel/include folder?  Other than installing them there.  In my case, it's for an external project that needs to find things in a standard place.